# control M job is unabl to invoke the process in peoplesoft application

Tags: control-m

control M job is unable to invoke the process in peoplesoft application..

instead it is going to gree and in the log it says the job is dummy..

but the control M team confirmed that the job is a valid one as per the configuration in the job properties.

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Ask control-m team to uncheck the "Dummy job" checkbox from the job properties tab.